# Arrays messed up C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
const int N = 5;

int person[] = {2, 3, 12, 5, 19};
int big = 0;
int small = 100;
int i;

for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    cout << "Person[" << i << "] ate: " << person[i] << endl;
    //cin >> person[i];

    for (int j = i+1; j <= N; j++)
    {
        if (person[i] < person[j])
        {
            int tmp = person[i];
            person[i] = person[j];
            person[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
            if (person[i]>big)
        big=person[i];
    if (person[i]<small)
        small=person[i];
}
    cout << "Person[" << i << "] ate the most pancakes: " << big << endl;
    cout << "Person[" << i << "] ate the least pancakes: " << small << endl;

    cout << "Sorted:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Person[" << i << "]: " << person[i] << endl;
    }




    system("pause");
```

[output](http://prikachi.com/images/470/8214470z.png)

Where I messed up those arrays it keeps showing me 2 but the bubble sorting works. And the other question is how to get the array index from the smallest value and the array index from the highest value?

Comment: The problem is you're going out of bounds, instead of `i <=  N` and `j <= N` you need: `i < N` and `j < N`, remember that C++ arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: *how to get the array index from the smallest value and the array index from the highest value?* - [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ arrays are *ZERO* `0` [indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). So you should change your for loops like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
             ^^^
{
    // some code...
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
                       ^^^
    {
        // some code...
```

Because:

```
index    -> 0  1  2   3  4 
person[] = {2, 3, 12, 5, 19};
```

In your code the value of `i` and `j` will increment up to `N` which is `5`. That means you are trying to access the array named `person`'s 5th index which will create array index out of bound error.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing starts from zero so if there are `N` elements, last element will be at `N-1` index.Accessing element at index `N` is going out of bounds.

```
for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)//should run till `N-1` 
              ^^^

for (int j = i+1; j <= N; j++)//should run till `N-1`
                     ^^^
```

If you want index of the highest and the lowest element,since you have sorted the array,the smallest values's index would be `0` and highest value's index will be `N-1`(opposite in your case because you have sorted the array in decreasing order)